# Cache images on android for several days

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

I need to cache image for let's say 14 days. On some web services I would set apache to do this with `ExpiresActive On` and `ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"`.

It's possible to do this with android? Of course I can store images on the phone storage, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

I read this [article (Caching Bitmaps)](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache) - but using `LruCache` and then calling `finish()` will destroy the cache, am I'm right or is there something I'm missing?

So are there any others solutions than saving files to phone's storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I solved it by using `SharedPreferences` and `File`

**How it works**

I have some json with base64 images string. And I need to store these values for 7 days. So I write the json to a File, save, put date string (creation date) to SharedPreferences.

1. User opens an activity
2. Get date from SP
3. Check if the date expired
4. Expired - make obtain new json from http request
5. !Expired - Check if json file exists
6. Exists - load json from file
7. !Exists - make obtain new json from http request and save to a file, update creation date

I'm not sure if this is the right solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Good analyze. But I think it would be better not to store as `Shared Preference` - Date.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). With this, you don't have to reinvent the wheel. You can cache the image thru this:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cache.build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, iv, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
...
}
```

There are also other options such as `cacheOnDisk(true)`.  This may not be the ultimate solution to your problem though if you require a specific number of days of the cache mechanism.

**EDIT**

Another good alternative is for you to use [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunPeriodic). Unfortunately, this is a pretty long topic so just follow the link I provided. To use it, you may have to create a `ContentProvider` for your app, then create a class that implements `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness :) that's great in the topic of periodical bitmaps update, but doesn't solve caching... Anyway +1 for Sync Adapter because I have never heard about it and it looks like a powerful tool.